# identifier highlighting and jumping stopped working

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, editor

I've had this problem come and go between different workspaces...

At some point identifier highlighting (with the cursor on an identifier, all other occurrences in scope get highlighted) and command-click on an identifier to jump to its definition both stopped working in some files.

These are java source files.  And there are no errors in the file or the file's project.  This is in the java perspective.

The problem is definitely not eclipse-wide or workspace-wide.  I can switch between java files and some work, some do not.  It may be project specific (a quick test shows it not working on two java files in the same project, but working on a java file from another project).

Thank you!
Matt

Comment: have you trying deleting your .metadata folder and starting again

Comment: Good idea, but deleting .metadata or creating a new workspace didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out my problem was not really with a broken file or workspace.  What happened was that I imported a project into my eclipse workspace.  Now this was a maven-based project -- a main project with the parent pom.xml in the main directory with many projects with their own pom.xml files directly below the main directory.

Apparently I imported the parent project (the main directory).  What I should have done was import the individual projects.

FWIW, if the parent directory doesn't have a pom, eclipse will see each of the projects in the subdirectories.  But with the parent pom in the top directory, it sees only the root project unless you drill down -- and each subproject has to be individually imported.

All is better now!  Which makes sense since it has all the source directories defined.  That's what tipped me off -- I was able to navigate to the directories, but they weren't showing up as source directories in the build path.